# ctags not working as expected with Vim plus general setup problems (C programming)

Tags: vim

I have installed cvim and NodeTree plugins and generated an exuberant ctags file for my build tree.

This is what my ~/.vim/.vimrc file looks like:

```
:noremap :TlistToggle
:let Tlist_Show_One_File = 1
:let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow = 1
:let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1 
set tags=./tags;/
set number
set tabstop=4
set incsearch
```

When I start editing a file, I notice that Ctrl ] does not work and I have to resort to typing `ta: funcname` - which gets tiring after a while. Interestingly enough, **Ctrl T** pops me off the tag stack as expected - I don't understand whats going on - how do I fix this?

Incidentally, vim (appears to) completely ignores the contents of my .vimrc file and I always have to type the same commands in the editor, so as to get the settings I want - very annoying.

Last but not the least, I used to be able to type `:make` in the editor window, drop to the console and then have the build results displayed in a little window which I can then go to and select a line (with an error or warning say), and then have the editor automagically take me to the offending line - unfortunately, I don't remember the plugin (or commands) I used to allow me to build from within vim.

So, how do I:

- Fix my vim setup so that I can move to definitions/declarations using **Ctrl-]**
- Fix my .vimrc file so that contents are actually applied to my vim session.
- Find the appropriate plugin to install to allow builds (using make) from within vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about a weird mix of problems.

#### Fix my vim setup so that I can move to definitions/declarations using Ctrl-]

The tags functionality is working; I suspect that you have a mapping blocking Ctrl-]. Try

```
:verbose nmap <C-]>
```

and

```
:nunmap <C-]>
```

#### Fix my .vimrc file so that contents are actually applied to my vim session.

```
:echo $MYVIMRC
```

will tell you the location of the .vimrc that Vim uses. Also, check the output of `:scriptnames` which scripts get loaded, and read `:help vimrc` to understand the logic Vim applies.

#### Find the appropriate plugin to install to allow builds (using make) from within vim

That's built into Vim. With the appropriate `'makeprg'` set (it defaults to `make`), you can run `:make`. Vim parses the output (through the `'errorformat'` option), and you can open the *quickfix list* via `:copen`.

Comment: `:verbose <C-]>` gives me:  **Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/clang_complete.vim**  , `nunmap <C-]>` gives me: **E31: No such mapping** and `:echo $MYVIMRC` returns nothing!

Comment: That's a good start! So, the clang_complete plugin "steals" the mapping, and you don't seem to have any _vimrc. Start one via `:edit ~/.vimrc`.

Comment: :Thanks for pointing out how to resolve issue 3. regarding issue 2, I moved my ~/.vim/.vimrc to the location you suggested. This fixes issue 3 (thanks!). Only issue 1 remains now.

Comment: Regarding issue 1: You can reconfigure the plugin's key: `let g:clang_jumpto_declaration_key = '...'`.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit slow, but I did not understand your last comment. I mean, what do I need to do to get **<C-]>** back as the jump to declaration key combo?. I mean I typed `let g:clang_jumpto_declaration_key = '<C-]'` in the editor (to make sure it works before adding it to my .vimrc file, but it had no effect. Issue 1 remains unresolved. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: You need to reassign the plugin's mapping to another key, e.g. `let g:clang_jumpto_declaration_key = '<F1>'`

Answer (score 0):

Your vimrc is:

```
~/.vim/.vimrc
```

If you run Vim 7.4, it should be:

```
~/.vim/vimrc
```

or

```
~/.vimrc
```

If you run Vim 7.3 or older, it should be:

```
~/.vimrc
```

And... what Ingo said.